# LinkedIn authentication issue in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, linkedin-api

I AM trying to Integrate LinkedIn with android. Using tutorials I have applied following code...

```
private void setWebView()
    {
        LinkedinDialog.oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        LinkedinDialog.factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);

        LinkedinDialog.liToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkitWebView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Log.i("LinkedinSample", LinkedinDialog.liToken.getAuthorizationUrl());
        mWebView.loadUrl(LinkedinDialog.liToken.getAuthorizationUrl());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

        mWebView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener()
        {
            public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture)
            {
                if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss(); 
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

I get following error at

```
LinkedinDialog.liToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);




07-22 17:32:08.026: E/AndroidRuntime(26733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 17:32:08.026: E/AndroidRuntime(26733): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.devicebee.app.transportfinder/com.devicebee.app.transportfinder.LinkedInActivity}: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
```

I have searched Internet and according to some posts it is because I am under some proxy. But I am pretty sure that I am not under any proxy. Kindly if anyone can tell me what to do.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this is what I have used and it works fine now

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClient;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInAccessToken;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthService;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInRequestToken;

public class LITestActivity extends Activity {


    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "xx";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "xx";
    private final static String APP_PNAME = "xx";


    public static final String APP_NAME = "xx;
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "xx";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "xxx";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME
            + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;

    final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory
            .getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(CONSUMER_KEY,
                    CONSUMER_SECRET);
    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
            .newInstance(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
    LinkedInApiClient client;

//  TextView tv = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        try
        {
        liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken
                .getAuthorizationUrl()));
        startActivity(i);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        try{
        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(
                liToken, verifier);
        client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
        String tweet = "Download Android App " + "market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME;
        client.postNetworkUpdate(tweet);
        //Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
        //tv.setText(p.getLastName() + ", " + p.getFirstName());
    //      p.setCurrentStatus("tweet");

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finish();

    }
}
```

Libraries are

```
linkedin-j-android.jar
signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar
signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
```

Comment: Great!! I'm using the exact same code but I keep getting "Access to posting shares denied" any ideas what might be causing that?? I tried to add permissions using scope but it just gets ignored

Comment: Hi, my app is working fine with LinkedIn, but I am receiving this error on devices with Ice-Cream Sandwich **Communication with the service provider failed: null**. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are trying to run this on your UI thread where network is not allowed.  You will need to implement the oauth calls in an AsyncTask.

Network calls on the UI thread were allowed until Android 3.0.  The tutorial you are following was probably written before that change happened.

--EDIT--
To test if this is true, you can try setting your application target to API 10 and see if the problem goes away.